# RotationalMotors of double-joint robot

Tags: webots

I'm writing a double joint robots and its controller for a forward kinematics example.

An interesting thing is that the second rotational motor attached to the first rotational motor with a link starts moving to the target position only after the first one has reached the target position.

I expected two rotation motors would move independently.

The world file and the controller are as follows:

```
#VRML_SIM R2019b utf8
WorldInfo {
}
Viewpoint {
  orientation 1 0 0 4.71238898038469
  position 0 1.86 0
}
TexturedBackground {
}
TexturedBackgroundLight {
}
RectangleArena {
}
DEF TARGET Transform {
  translation 0.2 0 0
  children [
    Transform {
      translation 0 0.005 0
      children [
        Shape {
          appearance Appearance {
            material Material {
              diffuseColor 1 0 0
              transparency 0.2
            }
          }
          geometry Cylinder {
            height 0.02
            radius 0.01
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
DEF ROBOT Robot {
  translation 0 0.005 0
  children [
    Shape {
      geometry Cylinder {
        height 0.02
        radius 0.001
      }
    }
    HingeJoint {
      jointParameters HingeJointParameters {
        axis 0 1 0
      }
      device [
        RotationalMotor {
          name "j0"
        }
      ]
      endPoint Solid {
        translation 0.05 0 0
        children [
          Shape {
            appearance Appearance {
              material Material {
                diffuseColor 0 0 0
              }
            }
            geometry Box {
              size 0.1 0.01 0.01
            }
          }
          SliderJoint {
            jointParameters JointParameters {
              axis 1 0 0
            }
            device [
              LinearMotor {
                name "d0"
              }
            ]
            endPoint Solid {
              children [
                Transform {
                  translation 0.05 0 0
                  children [
                    Shape {
                      geometry Cylinder {
                        height 0.02
                        radius 0.001
                      }
                    }
                    HingeJoint {
                      jointParameters HingeJointParameters {
                        axis 0 1 0
                      }
                      device [
                        RotationalMotor {
                          name "j1"
                        }
                      ]
                      endPoint Solid {
                        translation 0.05 0 0
                        children [
                          Shape {
                            appearance Appearance {
                              material Material {
                                diffuseColor 0 0 0
                              }
                            }
                            geometry Box {
                              size 0.1 0.01 0.01
                            }
                          }
                          SliderJoint {
                            jointParameters JointParameters {
                              axis 1 0 0
                            }
                            device [
                              LinearMotor {
                                name "d1"
                              }
                            ]
                            endPoint Solid {
                              children [
                                Shape {
                                  appearance Appearance {
                                    material Material {
                                      diffuseColor 1 1 1
                                    }
                                  }
                                  geometry Box {
                                    size 0.1 0.009 0.009
                                  }
                                }
                                Transform {
                                  translation 0.05 0 0
                                  children [
                                    Shape {
                                      appearance Appearance {
                                        material Material {
                                          diffuseColor 0 0 1
                                        }
                                      }
                                      geometry Box {
                                        size 0.011 0.011 0.011
                                      }
                                    }
                                  ]
                                }
                              ]
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
                Shape {
                  appearance Appearance {
                    material Material {
                      diffuseColor 1 1 1
                    }
                  }
                  geometry Box {
                    size 0.1 0.009 0.009
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
  controller "my_controller"
  supervisor TRUE
}
```

```
from controller import Supervisor

import math
import random
import numpy as np

def calculateEndPoint(j0, d0, j1, d1):
    m0 = np.array([[math.cos(j0), -math.sin(j0), d0 * math.cos(j0)],
                   [math.sin(j0), math.cos(j0),  d0 * math.sin(j0)],
                   [0,            0,             1]])
    m1 = np.array([[math.cos(j1), -math.sin(j1), d1 * math.cos(j1)],
                   [math.sin(j1), math.cos(j1),  d1 * math.sin(j1)],
                   [0,            0,             1]])
    v = np.array([0, 0, 1]).transpose()

    ret = np.matmul(np.matmul(m0, m1), v)

    return [ret[0], ret[1]]

class MyController(Supervisor):
    TIME_CHANGE_CONFIGURATION = 2
    D_OFFSET = 0.1
    J_MIN = 0
    J_MAX = 2 * math.pi
    D_MIN = 0
    D_MAX = 0.1

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.target = self.getFromDef("TARGET")

        self.j0 = self.getMotor("j0")
        self.d0 = self.getMotor("d0")
        self.j1 = self.getMotor("j1")
        self.d1 = self.getMotor("d1")

    def run(self):
        last_configuration_changed = 0

        while self.step(int(self.getBasicTimeStep())) != -1:
            if self.getTime() - last_configuration_changed > self.TIME_CHANGE_CONFIGURATION:
                # generate random configuration
                j0 = random.uniform(self.J_MIN, self.J_MAX)
                d0 = random.uniform(self.D_MIN, self.D_MAX)
                j1 = random.uniform(self.J_MIN, self.J_MAX)
                d1 = random.uniform(self.D_MIN, self.D_MAX)

                # call assignment function to get the coordinate of the end effector
                [x, y] = calculateEndPoint(j0, d0 + self.D_OFFSET,
                                           j1, d1 + self.D_OFFSET)

                # move the red box to the result
                self.target.getField("translation").setSFVec3f([x, 0, -y])

                # control motor
                self.j0.setPosition(j0)
                self.d0.setPosition(d0)
                self.j1.setPosition(j1)
                self.d1.setPosition(d1)

                # update last updated time
                last_configuration_changed = last_configuration_changed + self.TIME_CHANGE_CONFIGURATION

controller = MyController()
controller.run()
```

The links have 0 mass values, so I don't think it's caused by the torque limit.

What am I missing?

Comment: It seems you just found a bug in Webots. I just open an issue here https://github.com/cyberbotics/webots/issues/929 I also expect that the maxForce/Torque shouldn't be taken into account in such case. The workaround for now is to increase your RotationalMotor maxTorque/Force (the ones of the second pair of joints). Please monitor the GitHub issue to be informed on the progress about this issue.

Comment: Finally, it's more a matter of understand how kinematics mode is behaving than a bug. I created this documentation fix: https://github.com/cyberbotics/webots/issues/929 Is it more clear explained like this?